# How to assign action to broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My code is supposed to listen to callbacks which are made when a bluetooth headset pairs on unpairs.

```
 //The BroadcastReceiver that listens for bluetooth broadcasts
private final BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "paired", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "unpaired", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
```

The `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED` fires when bluetooth device is connected, but `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED` never shows any toast.

I am guessing this is because I haven't assigned the filters/actions properly in `onCreate` :

```
  IntentFilter BluetoothFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    registerReceiver(bReceiver, BluetoothFilter);
```

How do I add `ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED` in `oncreate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**
Add `BluetoothFilter.addAction(ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED)` before your `registerReceiver`.

Comment: Please comment in english.

Comment: I have tried waiting for literally 10 minutes after disconnecting my bluetooth headset, the toast however, never displayed.

Comment: I know I have to do that... but where do I insert that ? please try it yourself it does not let you.

Comment: I have to add both CONNECTED and DISCONNECTED

Comment: I just did. what problem are you facing while trying to addAction?

Comment: I will be surprised if this is possible. How did you do it? can I see your code?

Comment: Like is said , I have to add both CONNECTED and DISCONNECTED . How do I add BOTH? it only lets me use ONE NOT BOTH

Comment: Buddy, add action adds the new filters in your list. Actions are stored in the array list.
    IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);        
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);